# Ruby add string to the object with interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add `"*"` to the object. So I was thinking to do something like

```
  def initialize(search:)
    @search = search + "*"
  end
```

it works but I think this is not quite elegant way to do it. What is the better, more efficient way?

Comment: `@search = "#{search} *"` that can works

Comment: Why do you want to / have to add `*`?

Comment: @Stefan to search more precisely

Comment: In that case I'd just store the search term and append `*` when actually executing the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to do it this way

```
@search = "#{search}*"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#string-interpolation) says these are ok:

```
@search = "#{search}*"
```

or

```
@search = format('%s%s', search, "*")
```